# VS2008 and WinCe 6.0

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

I'm new to smart device development.
Is there WinCe 6.0 emulator which I can run fron VS2008?
I found WinCe 5.0 emulator and how to run in VS2008, but with 6.0 no luck.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft quit shipping a generic pre-built Emulator because the reality was that whatever emulator they chose, it never really matched anyone's actual device.  Platform Builder 6.0 ships with a Device Emulator BSP in the box and it's pretty easy to create one.

If you're in the situation where you don't have Platform Builder (e.g. you're only an app dev) then your choices are limited  You either need to ask your hardware provider if they have an emulator or just develop targeting a real device.  Personally I'd opt for the second, as I've rarely had good luck with the emulators (though to be fair I quit using them for much of anything back in the 3.0/4.2 days) and debugging on hardware is just as fast or faster.

Comment: @ctacke Is there an official statement issued by MSFT confirming what you said about MSFT ditching the idea of shipping a generic pre-built emulator?

Answer (score 2):

Let me point out that ctacke's recommendations are your best options. That said, if you just want to experiment and you still need an emulator, there is a book called "[Programming Windows® Embedded CE 6.0 Developer Reference, Fourth Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/mspress/companion/9780735624177/)" that comes with one, you just need to [download and install the code samples](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=101620&clcid=0x409) and you will get an emulator in VS 2008.

Comment: Good call.  I'd forgotten about the book's downloads

Comment: You saved my day! The emulator included in code samples is what I needed!